# Issue connecting to a database docker container in Windows from an application running in WSL2

Tags: docker, containers, wsl-2

I have installed Docker Desktop in Windows 11 and have a database container running that I can successfully connect to from my application using Visual Studio Toolchain with the following credentials:

```
host: localhost
port: 8233
user: root
```

I am trying to run the same application from within a WSL 2 Linux distro to connect to the database container that is running in Windows. The Docker Desktop is already configured for WSL integration and I can run `docker` command in my WSL terminal.

My application is also successfully built for WSL 2 but when I execute it I get the following error message.

```
Error connecting to Server: Can't connect to local server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Is there any way that I can connect to the database container running in Windows from a WSL Linux distro?

Comment: Can you show output of ipconfig from terminal of windows?